# Android code works in development but failed in play store

Tags: java, android, google-play

Sorry about bad English first.

I'm writing(or finding, copying) some codes to change app language. It works when I'm building through android studio. But after I push it on google play store, the codes failed!

I had logged it very completely, and 95% sure there's no bug in my code.

First part is copied from stackoverflow.

```
package com.my.package;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by devdeeds.com on 18/4/17.
 * by Jayakrishnan P.M
 */

public class LocaleHelper {
    private static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "en";
    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        Log.i("lang", "getLanguage");

        String lang = getPersistedData(context);
        Log.i("lang", "getLanguage, lang = "+lang);
        return lang;
    }

    public static Context setPrevLanguage(Context context) {
        Log.i("lang", "setPrevLanguage");

        String lang = getLanguage(context);
        Log.i("lang", "setPrevLanguage, prev lang = "+lang);
        return _setLang(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context setLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        Log.i("lang", "setLanguage");
        getPersistedData(context);
        persist(context, language);
        getPersistedData(context);
        return _setLang(context, language);
    }

    private static Context _setLang(Context context, String lang) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, lang);
        }
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, lang);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context) {
        Log.i("lang", "getPersistedData");
        Log.i("lang", "getPersistedData, applic ID = "+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lang = prefs.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
        Log.i("lang", "getPersistedData, lang = "+lang);
        return lang;
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration activityConf = resources.getConfiguration();
        Locale newLocale = new Locale(language);
        activityConf.setLocale(newLocale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(activityConf, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        Resources applicationRes = context.getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Configuration applicationConf = applicationRes.getConfiguration();
        applicationConf.setLocale(newLocale);
        applicationRes.updateConfiguration(applicationConf, applicationRes.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context.createConfigurationContext(activityConf);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;

    }
}
```

Second part is how I use them.

```
//when changing app language based on previous setting
LocaleHelper.setPrevLanguage(StartActivity.this);
LocaleHelper.setPrevLanguage((HomeActivity)this); 

//when setting app language through Setting/Language
String lang = "fil";  //its an app for fillipino
LocaleHelper.setLanguage(getContext(), lang);
```

When running

```
LocaleHelper.setPrevLanguage(StartActivity.this);
```

, it logs correctly in both debugging(build through android studio) and play-store version.
But only debugging version will change app version well, play-store version wont.

Is there somebody also confronted with that, the same codes do diffrent works in debugging and play-store version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess. If you are using [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) then your app is split to reduce download size. One of the ways it does this is only deliver the Locales used on the phone. It detects when the user changes the Locale through the OS and downloads the extra strings. But when you use your code, it probably won't happen.

To see if this is the problem you could try using an APK rather than a bundle, or not [enable splits](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/).